# Bloqueando rotas para usuários não logados

Tags: angularjs, login, rotas

eu estou fazendo uma aplicação e agora que ela está quase completa eu estava testando os ataques. Percebi que com as rotas do ngRoute a aplicação está vulnerável a entradas url.

Exemplo, a aplicação começa redirecionando para a página de login, mas se eu for na url e digitar o nome de uma página especifica, ele entra sem precisar logar.
Graças ao token, o usuário não pode fazer nenhuma interação com a aplicação, mas ainda assim ele tem acesso ao conteúdo que não faz requisição ao back.

A minha situação, eu procurei na internet e achei algumas coisa sobre um atributo no angularjs chamado resolve.
Tentei implementar ele, mas sem sucesso.
A pergunta, existe alguma forma no angularjs de bloquear todas as rotas para quem não está logado?
Se sim, como?

Answer (score 0):

Eu geralmente faço assim, talvez seja útil para você:

*Arquivo app.module.js*

```
angular.module('ModuloDaApp', ['LoginController', 'AdminController', 'UserController', 'ngRoute'])
    .run(preAtivador);

function preAtivador($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if ($location.path() == '/login') {
            localStorage.clear();
        }
        if (next.authorize) {
            if (!localStorage.token) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $location.path('#!/login');
            }
        }
    });
}
preAtivador.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location'];
```

*Arquivo app.routes.js*

```
angular.module('ModuloDaApp')
    .config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: '../views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            controllerAs: 'Login'
        })
        .when('/profile/admin', {
            templateUrl: '../views-admin/profile.html',
            controller: 'AdminController',
            controllerAs: 'Admin',
            authorize: true
        })
        .when('/profile/user', {
            templateUrl: '../views-user/profile.html',
            controller: 'UserController',
            controllerAs: 'User',
            authorize: true
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        })
    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
config.$inject = ['$routeProvider']
```

Comment: Esse authorize: true , serve pra bloquear por hierarquia né?
Vou testar essa forma, obrigado pela resposta fera.

Comment: Vlw ai fera, mas não deu certo.
Ainda consigo acessar outras páginas via url sem estar logado.

Comment: esse `authorize: true` adiciona um parametro chamado `authorize` com valor true a rota. Esse valor é recuperado no método `preAtivador` em `if (next.authorize)`, se o  atributo for settado ele entra nesse if.

Comment: no meu caso eu tenho um objeto no `LocalStorage` chamado `token`, esse é um token de acesso que o usuário recebe ao fazer o login. Se você utilizar outra forma de login e acesso pode fazer, por exemplo, que quando o usuário logue no sistema uma variavel booleana seja settada no localStorage: `localStorage.logado = true` daí substitua o `localStorage.token` por `localStorage.logado`

Comment: Vlw man, vou testar agora.
Eu tbm uso token pra validar login, tomara que seja fácil de implementar e funcional esse localStorage.token = true ^^